# Regex to capture a Wordpress v2.6.0/2.6.1 hash

Tags: python, regex, wordpress, python-2.7, hash

I have a hash that sits inside of a file:

```
Wordpress list:
eÝ>l;\x90\x9e(qNCDbf]_LÇa\x04\x0bTZZ
\x8aW\x8flëL\x03Z[esc]\x8e`R*\x87\,LÇa\x04\x0bTZZ
a\x9c[ff]\x04RýÎ\x03,ÔJANetáLÇa\x04\x0bTZZ
$H$91234567894GGuEJpikxPnFVUioh9e.
```

What I need to do is match the wordpress hash with a regex and output what line it was on. I've already done so, but I'm looking for a better regex if possible, the one I am using right now looks like this: `^\$H\$\d+\w+.$`. Here is how I am using it:

```
import re 

file_string = """
Wordpress list:
eÝ>l;\x90\x9e(qNCDbf]_LÇa\x04\x0bTZZ
\x8aW\x8flëL\x03Z[esc]\x8e`R*\x87\,LÇa\x04\x0bTZZ
a\x9c[ff]\x04RýÎ\x03,ÔJANetáLÇa\x04\x0bTZZ
$H$91234567894GGuEJpikxPnFVUioh9e."""
wordpress_re = re.compile(r"^\$H\$\d+\w+.$")

def find_wordpress_hash(data=file_string):
    for count, line in enumerate(data.split("\n"), start=1):
        if wordpress_re.match(line):
            print("Matched at line: {}".format(count))
            print(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_wordpress_hash()

# <= Matched at line: 6
# <= $H$91234567894GGuEJpikxPnFVUioh9e.
```

Is there a more accurate regex I could be using, or a better way to use this regex, or even a better way to capture a wordpress 2.6.0/2.6.1 hash?

Comment: Your pattern only matches digits followed by word characters. Use `^\$H\$[a-zA-Z\d]+\.$`.

Comment: the only think I can think of is if the hash always ends in `.` your regex `"^\$H\$\d+\w+.$"` should be `"^\$H\$\d+\w+\.$"`.

Comment: I created the regex to match this hash specifically, is there a way to match all possible wordpress 2.6.0/2.6.1 hashes?

Comment: @secxit Probably, but hard to say for sure without knowing what wordpress hashes look like.